# Effect with margins?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-editor

The design is a Linearlayout with a cardivew inside and a background color, that simple.

By clicking on any view (View 1, View 2 ...) other layouts are added dynamically. These new layouts "push" the Linearlayout that holds the Cardview. I think that this does not influence the effect I want to achieve.

[image]

I would like to get the effect that you see in the next image.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For that You need to use ConstraintLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="linearLayout"/>

   <LinearLayout>
   ....Your Layout Code.....
   </LinearLayout/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```